# Form - Prepopulate and hide field with given argument

Tags: entities

I have two content types: City and Request.
Request is entity referenced to city.

Now i created a custom themed node /berlin.
On this page i have a button that says "send request", which brings you to the node/add/request form.

The form should now somehow pre-populate the field "field-city" with the previously selected city entity/node.

Additionally the field should be hidden.

Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a dev version of the [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module for Drupal 7:

> The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable.
>
> For example, the following URL,
>
> http://www.example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this is the title
>
> will automatically fill the Title field on a new blog post with the words "this is the title". Any field can be prepopulated this way, including taxonomy and CCK fields. You can prepopulate more than one field at a time as well. Prepopulate is excellent for creating bookmarklets. For examples on usage for all of these cases, please read the USAGE.txt file that comes with the module or you can read the online handbook page.

So you would just have to craft that button on your City node page to include the additional variable for your city field.

If for whatever reason this doesn't work exactly to your liking, eg, I am not sure if it allows for hiding of the prepopulated field, it would be fairly trivial to craft the functionality in a form_alter() hook in a custom module.

Comment: the plugin indeed helps. now i need to figure out how to hide the field...

Answer (score 1):

After some more research i came across a module that does exactly what i need!
Prepopulating a entity reference field and hiding the form field.

https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate

Answer (score 0):

The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable. Maybe you could use that module to fill the city field on the add form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Node Reference URL Widget](https://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) to auto-populates the field form url and its value can't be change later on. For More information go through the documentation of this module. 
 For Entity reference use [Entityreference prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module.

Comment: this plugin can't handle entity reference.